# Отправка заголовков в NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, angular

В серверной части использую вот такие используемые заголовки

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, DELETE');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  next();
});
```

При запросе данных через Postman все отлично приходит. А если пытаюсь запросить через Angular 6 получаю в ответ вот такую ошибку. Данные не приходят и даже к серверу запроса нет.

```
Failed to load http://localhost:3000/api/v1.0/auth: Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

Вот так выгледит запрос:

```
interface ProfileData {
  login: string,
  access: string,
  token: string
}
const headers = new HttpHeaders({ 
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, DELETE',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With'
});

authorization(login, password){
    return this.http.post<ProfileData>(this.uri + 'auth', {login, password}, { headers: headers });
}
```

Внутри компонента вызываю вот так

```
this.auth.authorization(login, password).subscribe(data => console.log(data));
```

Может у кого есть какие мысли. Говорите буду пробовать.

Comment: Как мне кажется, вам не надо в запросе передавать заголовки `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` и `'Access-Control-Allow-Headers`.

Comment: что такое `app` express ?  [тут](https://enable-cors.org/server_expressjs.html) пишут что нужно `app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});`

Comment: Да это express.  Пробовал в запросе не отправлять выдает POST http://localhost:3000/api/v1.0/auth 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: а тут есть целый плагин https://github.com/expressjs/cors

Comment: но это всё, конечно, если ошибка в корс

Comment: "и даже к серверу запроса нет" это в инструментах разработчика, во вкладке сеть?

Comment: а плагин cors он сам шапки получается контролит?

Comment: Вот 500 ошибка если есть, то CORS уже прошли, сервер отработал, но случилась ошибка. Смотрите ошибку и дальше решайте.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Нашел проблему.     authorization(login, password){
        return this.http.post<ProfileData>(this.uri + `auth?login=${login}&password=${password}`, {});
    }  вот в таком теле запрос вернулся норм. Получается по тому как я пытался он не отсылал туда вообще ничего. я на сервере отлавливал запрос и получал undefined